# How do I install Xposed Framework on Android x86 running in Virtual Box?

Tags: xposed-framework, android-x86, virtualbox

I downloaded Android Marshmallow from the Android x86 project and installed it on Virtual Box. I am now running Marshmallow on Virtual Box on my Mac computer.

I looked up instructions on how to install Xposed Framework on Android, only to later realize that it is mostly intended to be used on devices with ARM processors, like smartphones. I have heard, however, that some people have been able to get it working on android emulators running on computers. I am wondering how I might be able to do this on virtual box with the Marshmallow version of Android x86.

I tried to use the instructions listed here: [How can I install flashable zips in Android-x86](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150929/how-can-i-install-flashable-zips-in-android-x86)

The answerer gives "fool-proof" steps, which I was able to follow. After I complete Step 14, however, the Terminal Emulator app gives me this error: "Extracted file system/xposed.prop not found!"

[image]

Does anyone have any advice for what I can do to fix this? Or should I be going down a completely different path than what I am now trying? I know that on phones, the normal process of installing Xposed involves a custom recovery and whatnot, but I am not sure that is possible on an emulator.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I see you made a mistake,you should do `cd` then the derectory of the extracted file then `sh flash-script.sh` such as `su` enter `cd /sdcard/download/` file name `/META-INF/com/google/android`/ enter" `sh flash-script.sh`

Comment: You'll probably encounter an error if your running a 64 bit version that its the wrong version.Should work on x86,havent tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, first install a 32 bit version of Android x86, then go [HERE](https://androidforums.com/threads/guide-installing-xposed-without-flashfire.1071558/) and download the needed files, then modify `installer.bin` to where it says please download the correct zip put a `#` at the beginning of the 3 `echo` and `exit` so it looks like this:

```
 #echo -e "The processor architecture and Xposed version are different."
 #echo -e "Please download the correct zip."
 #echo "sleep 2"
 #exit 0
```

Follow the rest of the instructions and you have xposed. Sorry my last post was incorrect.

I also recommend installing supersu due to a bug in android x86 root, install supersu 2.79 install binary reboot then you can update.